# Serializing complex class instances as nodes within NetworkX

Tags: json, serialization, networkx

Amateur here, please be patient!

PREAMBLE:

I have a networkX graph where all of the nodes are instances of a class or some subclass thereof. I.E:

```
class Qnode:
    def __init__(self, **atts)
    ...
    Etc.

G = nx.graph()
G.add_node(Qnode(**atts))
```

I'm interested in serialising my graph so I can send it to someone else. At the moment I think the best way to do this is with adjacency_data()

A simple example:

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
simple = nx.Graph([(1, 2)])
data = json_graph.adjacency_data(simple)
print(data)

>>> {'directed': False, 'multigraph': False, 'graph': [], 'nodes': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}], 'adjacency': [[{'id': 2}], [{'id': 1}]]}
```

Which can then be dumped into a JSON object.

When I do this for my graph of qnode objects, it appears to correctly serialise, but writes down my values as pointers to my Qnodes, which isn't useful for the receiving party.

Example of a one node graph with my qNode object as a networkx node:

```
{'directed': False, 'multigraph': False, 'graph': [], 'nodes': [{'id': <Node.Qnode object at 0x7fadeedbcda0>}
```

MAIN QUESTION::

What's the easiest way for me to unpack my objects so that I can send everything without reference to pointers? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you considered pickle?

Comment: I've heard of pickle but I haven't considered it seriously yet. I'm honestly a little nervous about serialising into something that I the human can't read. That said, I had a look at the documentation and it seems like it might be the solution I'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestion!